# tool stripping white-spaces in diff

Tags: diff, debian, patch, removing-whitespace

commiting in hg create diff files.

But, i would like to be able to look at a factorized version of these diff, ignoring all white-spaces.

I have a lot a diff files (905 files) between two revisions, and i need such a tool to understand the changes of code.

Basically, the tool would open a diff file (or patch), reconstruct the old file then compare it with the current one ignoring white-spaces and finally optimaly show the comparison to me in a GUI with side-by-side code.

Is there such a tool?

By the way, I am on Debian 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware of [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), and similar tools for visually comparing diffs, right? You can also use [the Mercurial extdiff extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) to integrate usage of kdiff3 and other such tools into mercurial. Kdiff3 has a 'show white space' button (it's a white square) you can toggle on and off, but I don't know it that is what you want.

[Tortoisehg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) is another option for viewing diffs.

Mercurial's diff has a -w command. See

```
-w --ignore-all-space     ignore white space when comparing lines
```

Comment: Thank you. kdiff3 will provide me a great help. It is not exactly what I were looking for, but it should be more than enough. I wanted an "editor" that can open a diff file, then refactor it by stripping white-spaces.